# Create a prop for a chart.js pie chart

Tags: reactjs, react-native, chart.js, react-chartjs

I'm using Chart.js inside my react project.
and i want to structure my project as neatly as possible by creating components
and calling them on my App.js

How can I go about creating a react prop and calling it from another component without Actually calling my pie chart from the App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Pie} from 'react-chartjs-2';

const state = {
  labels: ['January', 'February', 'March',
           'April', 'May'],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Rainfall',
      backgroundColor: [
        '#B21F00',
        '#C9DE00',
        '#2FDE00',
        '#00A6B4',
        '#6800B4'
      ],
      hoverBackgroundColor: [
      '#501800',
      '#4B5000',
      '#175000',
      '#003350',
      '#35014F'
      ],
      data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56]
    }
  ]
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Pie
          data={state}
              options={{
              title:{
              display:true,
              text:'Average Rainfall per month',
              fontSize:20
            },
              legend:{
              display:true,
              position:'left',
             }
          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create a component named `PieChart` in the `PieChart.js` file like this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Pie } from 'react-chartjs-2';

export default class PieChart extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Pie
                    data={this.props.data}
                    options={{
                        title: {
                            display: true,
                            text: 'Average Rainfall per month',
                            fontSize: 20
                        },
                        legend: {
                            display: true,
                            position: 'left',
                        }
                    }}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Then you can import it from the `App.js` in this way:

```js
import React from 'react';

import PieChart from './PieChart';

const state = {
  labels: ['January', 'February', 'March',
    'April', 'May'],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Rainfall',
      backgroundColor: [
        '#B21F00',
        '#C9DE00',
        '#2FDE00',
        '#00A6B4',
        '#6800B4'
      ],
      hoverBackgroundColor: [
        '#501800',
        '#4B5000',
        '#175000',
        '#003350',
        '#35014F'
      ],
      data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56]
    }
  ]
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <PieChart data={state} />
    )
  }
}
```

Here I've created a custom `props` named `data` and passed it to the `PieChart` component which is being accessed by `this.props.data` in the `PieChart` component. You can create multiple props as you want. Like you can pass `options` as well in this way.

**Also you can keep your data(which is passed from the `App` as `data` props) in the `PieChart` component and call it from anywhere you want by `<PieChart />`**.

**Note: I've kept `App.js` and `PieChart.js` both files in the same directory.**

Answer (score -1):

This how I used piechart in my project:
in another file, you can create a custom component and add your code like below

```
export const StatusChart = ({ data }) => {
  const [pieData, setPieData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    setPieData({
      labels: ['declined', 'accepted', 'goterror', 'inprogress'],
      datasets: [
        {
          data: [data.inprogress, data.got_error, data.accepted, data.declined],
          backgroundColor: ['#F7464A', '#46BFBD', '#FDB45C', '#949FB1', '#4D5360'],
          hoverBackgroundColor: ['#FF5A5E', '#5AD3D1', '#FFC870', '#A8B3C5', '#616774'],
        },
      ],
    });
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <MDBContainer>
      <Pie data={pieData} options={{ responsive: true }} />
    </MDBContainer>
  );
};
```

and in App.js you can use useState to save data like below:

```
  const [generalData, setGeneralData] = useState(null);
```

and use it in your code:

```
{generalData ? <StatusChart data={generalData.status_chart} /> : <Spinner animation="border" />}
```